# Processing large file in java

Tags: java

I have twelve million records with me. Records are processed by sorting them and then using thread pool execution. But the process stops in between showing some memory issues.

Recently I saw a reply concerning this issue which was almost close to this.
The solution was to use *concurrent.Executor*. But when I referred to it, the concept seemed almost the same as a *thread pool*.

Are both of these different?
How can I run such a huge amount of records?

Please suggest some methods by which the efficiency can also be ensured.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to read all of the records into memory? Can you use a database of some kind instead?

Comment: You'll almost certainly have to batch the process. It's not reasonable to expect something this large to be processed synchronously, with a user waiting for results after a button click or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give you concrete answer without any code snippet, however I can give you some tips.

First, it is not clear for me why do you have to sort your items if then you process them using thread pool. If number of threads > 1 the order of processing is "random", so sorting data probably does not have any sense.

If you do not sort the data you should process them during reading, i.e. do not read all data into the memory, read them chunk-by-chunk and process them.

Anyway if you need more heap increase it using `-Xmx` command line switch of JVM.

If for some reason you have to sort your data anyway and increasing heap is not possible you probably should think about intermediate storage of sorted data.

I hope these tips help.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your valuable reply. As you said "read them chunk-by-chunk and process them", for the same purpose, I am sorting them, as the record is fetched into the process based on the data. For eg: If my file contains data with X,Y,Z ; X is fetched into a single process whereas "Y" into another. Hence, by sorting them the data with "X" can be fetched altogether and can be run at the same time. We have implemented "thread pool" concept without using the Executor package. Are these "Executor" and the thread pool concept same. Please guide me through. Thanks..

Comment: As I mentioned sorting is not needed here. It is OK to process different types of data using different threads, however this fact makes sorting irrelevant. I do not really understand why do yo say that you use different processes for A and B. Do you probably mean "threads"? BTW IMHO implementing your own thread pool is to waste time (unless it is a student project).

Comment: I found the bug Alex. As you said I go through the codes. And finally found that the issue is with the reader. The tips you mentioned were right. Well, I am going to post my next question, with the new issue. Thanks Alex